# npm run dev don't give me the link

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Please help me guys when I execute npm run dev I get this error :

failed to load config from C:\Windows\System32\react-app\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\react-app\vite.config.ts.timestamp-1690288065442-391efff42da45.mjs'

i think my problem seems to be related to the Vite configuration file (vite.config.ts). Specifically, Vite is failing to load the configuration file, and it's encountering a permission issue when trying to open another file related to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is connected with the directory from which you try to run the program. Try this:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\react-app 
npm run dev
```

Comment: or if you have another directory C:\Windows\System32\react-app\your-app

Comment: The solution didn't work

Comment: Then try to update your node version, maybe it will help

Comment: when i open the folder from cmd in vscode, it's work properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to appear because your project is in **System32** folder,  which is not the right place for your project files.

Move the project to different path other than (**System32**).

Install dependencies:

```
npm install
```

If the issue still persists then clear cache and retry using :

```
vite clear && npm run dev
```